# Laravel: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Guys I am trying to save in database like this

```
  public function postPayment(PaymentRequest $request){

          $insertPayment=Input::get();

          $payment= new paymentrecieved();
          $comment= new comments();

         $data=array();

          for($i = 0; $i < count($insertPayment['recieved_amount']); $i++) {

                if($insertPayment['adjustmentmode'][$i]=='Option')
                $adjust_mode='NONE';
                else
                  $adjust_mode=$insertPayment['adjustmentmode'][$i];
                  $data[] = [
                       'invoice_id' => $insertPayment['invoiceid'],
                       'recieved_amount' => $insertPayment['recieved_amount'][$i],
                      'refno' => $insertPayment['ref_no'][$i],
                      'date' => $insertPayment['date'][$i],
                       'adjust_mode' => $adjust_mode,
                       'adjust_amount' => $insertPayment['adjustmentamount'][$i]
                   ];

         }

          $result = paymentrecieved::create($data);
```

}

But I am getting the above error , I understood this is happening because I have Foreign Key in my model .

But I am not able to fix this

Can any one help me

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What exactly is the foreign key constraint?

Comment: @Satisfaction do you want me to post the migration of the paymentrecieved model ?

Comment: Just show me how is the foreign key formed.

Comment: ` Schema::table('Payments', function($table) {
           $table->foreign('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('event_invoice');
       });`  Hope this is what you mean

Comment: Does the input seem valid? Are you 100% sure that `$insertPayment['invoiceid']` is a valid invoice id?

Comment: @Satisfaction yes because I have validated it in the PaymentRequest class using the validator class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94702/discussion-between-vikram-and-satisfaction).